# Ubuntu is fast at one moment, but slow at the other moment

Tags: 14.04, performance, responsiveness

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on my computer that acts as a server. Short pc spec list (lshw): http://pastebin.com/7ud6rpxX

The average number of procs is 500 (I have got a little widget that I forgot the name of on my desktop)

The server is running a GitLab server on it with a runner connected to it, but it isn't doing anything at the time of being slow. There is not really any connection to the things the server does on GitLab and the performance of the system.

The one moment it's fast, the other it's slow.
Can't find out why, also the booting is very very slow (the terminal kind of bootdetails list is progressing very slow and takes it's time)

Should I disable the visual effects?

Thanks,

Tim

EDIT: I haven't found anything that uses my cpu above 2,5% and my memory above 8%. Could it be the GPU giving up?

EDIT: Here is the second bootchart image:

[HIGH RES](http://www.mediafire.com/view/s4ac39na9ob3sow/Bootchart.png)

EDIT: This is the bootchart with the ureadahead pack file removed:

[HIGH RES with pack file removed](http://www.mediafire.com/view/e9y4b0cz385tb94/Latest_bootchart.png)

[image: Bootchart of 16/04/25]

Comment: Image quality is too low. Something on top of booting is taking too long (maybe ureadahead - can't see)

Comment: @EdiD Sorry, didn't see that. Here is the file itself: http://www.mediafire.com/view/s4ac39na9ob3sow/Bootchart.png
The first big thing is indeed unreadahead

Comment: `ureadahead` is slowing boot try to purge cache by removing any pack files in the `/var/lib/ureadahead` directory.

Comment: @EdiD I think I might have the fix: clean your system from time to time. I think my GPU was thermal throttling that much that the whole system became slow.

Comment: Cleaning is definitely good but GPU has nothing to 50s `ureadahead` delay on boot

Comment: @EdiD That did not fixed it unfortunately. I'll check the bootchart since I did remove the pack file.

Comment: @EdiD Please check my updated question.

Comment: First boot after deleting pack files will rebuild ureadahead cache so it could be slower than normal. If next boot are the same slow try to disable ureadahead : `sudo tee /etc/init/ureadahead.override <<< manual`

Comment: @EdiD I was backing up my system so I couldn't reboot it. But bootchart showed a decrease of ureadahead 'waiting time' of around 1 minute. So it seems that this fix is working for now. Does disabling bootchart improve the booting time? Or can I just leave it enabled?

Comment: If everything is ok you may consider disabling

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to know what is causing this slows. You can monitor if your cpu is not excessive loaded:

```
watch "ps aux --sort -pcpu | head -11"
```

This will monitor every default 2s top 10 consuming cpu processes.
You can send it to log file for further investigation with a little `tee` help:

```
watch "ps aux --sort -pcpu | head -11 | tee -a logfile"
```

In the same way you can monitor memory usage

```
watch "ps aux --sort -rss | head -11"
```

For slow booting problems. You can install bootchart

```
sudo apt-get install bootchart
```

reboot your system and analyse chart which should be placed in `/var/log/bootchart`. It should tell you what causes slow boot. After all you can disable bootchart service with:

```
sudo tee -a /etc/init/bootchart.override <<< manual
```

---

You can also use tools like `top` for process monitoring and `iotop` for I/O operations and check logs `/var/log/syslog`,`/var/log/kern.log`, `/var/log/boot.log` for "suspicious" entries

Comment: Thanks for this, I am definitely going to try this! I will post the results in my question above.

Comment: Sorry for answering this late, I am having big time issues with my GitLab instance, which are not yet resolved. But I have attached the bootchart picture in the question. If you want me to send the tgz file, just pm me. Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry to say to, but the problem is still occuring, I'll try to boot to Windows on that machine to check if is an Ubuntu related issue. I am hoping it is, but on the other side I am not.